# Pygame - shooting bullets

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, 2d

I have problem with my code, I started to make 2D tank game, the problem is the shooting bullets from the tank position.. Here's my code, check it out, I'm trying to figure it out like 3-4 hours.. I hope someone knows how to do it, thanks!:)

by the way, sorry for the creepy code, I'm new to Pygame :)

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

#---WINDOW----
display_width = 1000
display_height = 600

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('powpypow')

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)




background = pygame.image.load('background.png')
tank1 = pygame.image.load('tank1.png')
tankfire = pygame.image.load('tankfire.png')
shot = pygame.image.load('shot.png')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def tank(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(tank1, (x,y))

x = (display_width * 0.10) 
y = (display_height * 0.58)

x_change = 0

tank_width = 73 


#---GAME LOOP----

gameExit = False


while not gameExit:

    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                x_change = -10
            elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                x_change = 10    
            elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                tank1 = pygame.image.load('tankfire.png')


        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a or event.key == pygame.K_d or event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                tank1 = pygame.image.load('tank1.png')
                x_change = 0 

    if x >= display_width - tank_width or x <= 0:
        x = 0
    if x > display_width / 2:
        x = 0 

    x += x_change
    gameDisplay.blit(background, (0,0))
    tank(x,y)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: What is the problem you're having? Are the bullets not appearing? Are they not moving in the right direction, at the right speed, etc.?

Comment: They're not appearing at all cuz I don't have any function yet.... Can't figure it out how to do that thing..

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to want to render bullets, you are going to need to keep track of them as they move across the screen. This will require some sort of list or group of bullets that you iterate through and draw, one at a time.

I recommend you have a look at a tutorial to help you switch to using Sprites in a group, rather than blitting each image onto the screen individually. You will find that it is much easier to track each object and adjust its position.

The Chimp tutorial from the Pygame website is pretty good: https://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/chimp/ChimpLineByLine.html